# 'Agree terms' or 'Agree TO terms'?

Tags: transitivity

I have had a disagreement with a teacher over the correct structure of a sentence.

My teacher said that the sentence "...and if they agree terms, they will have a deal." is correct. However, this sounds incorrect to me.

I would always say "...and if they agree to the terms, they will have a deal."

Could someone please tell me which is correct?

Comment: I'll bet you a beer that your teacher is British or learned English from a British background. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is British English versus American English.  Brits sometimes say *we agree the terms*. Yanks typically say *we agree* ***to*** *the terms*. Take your pick.

[Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=agree+the+terms%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+agree+the+terms%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+agree+to+the+terms%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+agree+to+the+terms%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cagree%20the%20terms%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cagree%20the%20terms%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cagree%20to%20the%20terms%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cagree%20to%20the%20terms%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) is one comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the UK, and I prefer "If they agree to/on the terms, they will have a deal". Having said that, I wouldn't bat an eyelid if I saw or or heard  "If they agree terms, they will have a deal".
It's not a question of which is correct, as both forms are acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct. *Agree* is an intransitive verb. Therefore, you cannot "agree terms"; you need to say, "agree to terms".

Comment: Also, "agree to _the_ terms" would suggest that there is a specific already-existing set of terms that they may agree to, as opposed to them negotiating to come up with terms, although I suppose it could be interpreted as "the terms of their deal".

Comment: @RickyDemer, in which case, as an American, I would say "agree to terms".

Comment: *"You are correct. Agree is an intransitive verb."* **This is simply wrong.** To agree is ambitransitive, i.e. it can be transitive or intransitive.